# Why does jQuery replaceWith only work once?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jQuery code that replaces data in a div each time the form is submitted. For some reason the `replaceWith` function is only replacing the `div` once? Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<div class="count"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#like_unlike").submit( function(e) { //Second Form
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "update_likes.php"; //Grab URL from form
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formdata);   
    $.post(url, formdata, function(response) {
      //Post the form
      $('.count').replaceWith(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Coz there's only one `.count`? Or you are targeting all the counts.

Comment: Does your `response` include a `.count` class in one of your elements?

Comment: Well... you are replacing .count - after replacement, no element with that class anymore, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't "replace data in a div" - it actually replaces the element, meaning you won't be able to select it anymore because `.count` will be gone after your code executes.

Instead, replace the inner HTML of `.count` with [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), which would look like:

```
$('.count').html(response);
```