# jQuery / ajax only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code, that works perfectly, however only once. After that I need to refresh the page. I know the Ajax request to PHP runs as I can see that...

Also `#addtocart` is outside of `#shopping_cart_content`.

Any ideas anyone?

```
                  $(document).on('click','#addtocart',function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();

                        var data = $(this).data('href');
                        $.ajax({
                            method: 'get',
                            url: '/index.php',
                            data: data,
                            async: true,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data){
                                element = "";
                                $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                                    if ( !isNaN(key) ) {
                                        if ( typeof value.volume !== 'undefined' && value.volume.length > 0 ){
                                            value.volume = '('+value.volume+')';
                                        }
                                        element = element + '<div><div class="shopping_item_count">'+value.count+' x </div>';
                                        element = element + '<img class="shopping_item_thumb" src="'+value.pic+'" />';
                                        element = element + '<strong>'+value.name+'</strong> <span class="shopping_small_txt">'+value.volume+'</span> <br />';
                                        element = element + '<span class="shopping_small_txt">'+value.count+'x &#8364; '+value.price+' = &#8364; '+value.count*value.price+'</span></div> ';
                                    }
                                }); 
                                element = element + '<div class="shopping_total_divider"></div>';
                                element = element + '<div class="shopping_total_txt">TOTAL: <span style="float: right;">&#8364; '+data.total+'</span></div>';
                                
                                $("#shopping_cart_content").replaceWith(element);   
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: You are using `$("#shopping_cart_content").replaceWith(element);`. Do like `$('#shopping_cart_content').append(element);`.

Comment: how does that affect the situation? if `replaceWith` limited to firing once?

Comment: I see what you mean @StackSlave, thanx for pointing in the right direction

Comment: I don't see anything limiting the firing to once. Maybe you have a form needs `$('#formId').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433240/why-does-jquery-replacewith-only-work-once